# UIImagePickerController leaking on iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, memory-leaks, uiimagepickercontroller

I've configured my `UIImagePickerController` for taking an image and for recording a video both independently. The `UIImagePickerController` is directly called from an `@IBAction` (by a `UIButton`). I receive both `UIImage` and `URL` from the video in the `imagePickerController` delegate method and print them for testing purposes.

After waiting a little while (10 seconds) I select Xcode's "View Memory Graph History" in which I can see that in both testing cases I have memory leaks and also cyclic references. I can also see those memory leaks in Instruments if someone thinks it's an Xcode bug.

This happens when I record a video:

[image: memory leaks video]

And this happens when I take a picture:

[image: memory leaks photo]

You can reproduce this results with this code on a iOS 11.2 device (I don't think simulators would work):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func takePhoto(_ sender: Any) {

        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.sourceType = .camera
        picker.allowsEditing = false

        self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func recordVideo(_ sender: Any) {

        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.sourceType = .camera
        picker.allowsEditing = false
        picker.mediaTypes = ["public.movie"]
        picker.videoQuality = .typeHigh

        self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String: Any]) {

        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            print(image.size)
        }

        if let video = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? URL {
            print(video.path)
        }
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Now my question is: Can I fix those with some workaround or am I doing something wrong in my code, is this a bug by Apple, should I just ignore it?

Edit: If anyone wants to take a look at the whole project: https://github.com/ph1ps/UIImagePickerLeak

Comment: I don't have this issue but I also do not use `UIImagePIckerController` for videos. But what jumps out at me is this line: `let picker = UIImagePickerController()` which is *inside* `recordVideo(sender:Any)`. First, how many instances of the controller are being created? Second, if you changed things from `Any` to `UIPickerViewController` - a very messy way for Xcode to default things IMO - does that help? Finally, do you have any other resources for using this controller for *videos*?

Comment: @dfd The `IBActions`s are only called once and it still happens. This also happens when taking pictures as I said. I will try creating the picker outside of the function.

Comment: @dfd Defining the picker outside of the `IBAction` doesn't change anything :(

Comment: If it happens with taking still images, I'm guessing you haven't given us the code causing the issue yet. I use `UIImagePickerController` in three apps with no issue. Most of my code is similar... beyond instantiating the picker more globally, and checking for a camera on the device. The latter *shouldn't* make any difference. If my one thought doesn't work, maybe you need to take a quick/small step back... create a project (not a framework), add things in (testing next on your framework), until you find the cause of the memory leak. Good luck.

Comment: @dfd I swear this is all the code to it. I posted my whole project on Github: https://github.com/ph1ps/UIImagePickerLeak . Maybe you could take a look and test it yourself.

Comment: I'm unable to *exactly* duplicate the issue. (I also think I'm using something different to profile things.) My try #1: (1) I moved the image picker declaration out to be globally available, then (2) moved all other duplicated code - except of course, the `present` - into `viewDidLoad`, then (3) commented out what remained in your video button action. I then ran `Product|Profile` to open up instruments, and chose `Leaks`. Taking multiple pictures I only had a `CASlotProxy` leak reported after 30 seconds....

Comment: And this leak you got is normal?

Comment: For try #2 I commented back in the video and took a picture then made a short video, about 5-7 seconds. I did get the same `CASlotProxy` leak at 30 seconds, but before that - at 20 seconds - I received a `CAMVideoCaptureRequest` leak. Not nothing I could find *matched* the screen shots in your question. So my question for you is - what are those? Maybe I'm doing something wrong. :-)

Comment: No those are the leaks I‘m getting too in Instruments but Xcode kinda displays them weirdly...

Comment: Can't reproduce it on iOS 11.2 iPhone8. Add `weak var _picker:UIImagePickerController?` and bind to to pickers in your two action, and add timer to print _picker, you will find there is no memory leak

Comment: @AndyDarwin Could you please do either a pull request your solution or post the code in an answer? I still can't make it work without a memory leak

Comment: Follow this blog for memory issue http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/3816-uiimagepickercontroller-memory-issues.html#post20911

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say just ignore the "leaks" you are seeing. While, I don't have any code to back this up, I do have some experience finding and fixing memory leaks on-the-job. In my experience, when you're finding leaks, you look for smoking guns. So for the memory graph history, I would suspect that there might be a memory leak if there were hundreds or thousands of instances of some type leaked. This goes for mobile apps as well. From what I can see from your screenshots, you're leaking at most 1k, which (assuming there even is a leak) is pretty trivial. As such, you really don't appear to have a leak.

Comment: I guess I have to stick with this solution. It just annoyed me that I couldn't fix this leak. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I add some code to prove there is no memory leak. You can judge it either by my code or memory graph. I've already made a pull request.

https://github.com/Andy1984/UIImagePickerLeak

Comment: The UIImagePickerController is not leaking but some objects which are somehow connected with it. I thought you could set some delegates to nil and they would gone. But still... Here's a screenshot
https://imgur.com/a/scEDu

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing all sorts of conflicting info on whether there's a leak or not.

First off... there is, it's the inconsistency of it that's frustrating people en masse.

I'm totally seeing retention when using UIImagePickerController. There *IS* some sort if issue with it. I've got a user profile editor that has two places to take/select an image (one for the person, one for his vehicle). When I use the EXACT same code for both, one releases just fine, and my profileEditViewController deinits just fine. When I use the other, even to cancel selection of an image, it does not release and my controller never deinits. Exact same code. 100% in both places.

I thought it came down to delegate retention, but I experimented with not setting delegation (thus rendering it basically useless) and the same results were plainly evident. Just initiating the second UIImagePickerController caused a retention lock, even declaring a whole other variable for the second one. I can get my controller to deinit by simply never initiating the second picker, however the memory doesn't drop.

It's retaining, even if disconnected from my controller. It's kind of silly when that's the case following Apple's strictest examples to the letter in production code :(

Comment: I just created a ImagePickerContoller singleton and did nothing else to my code. With one instance ever of the UIImagePickerController, my memory usage taking tens of photos is a fraction of what it was. I made no other changes besides not creating a new UIImagePIckerController for each photo I need to take. This sort of subverts others saying there is no leak. There is definitely some sort of memory problem, as you said!